# Perl Regex : Modification of a read-only value attempted

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to replace `whitespaces` in a string after matching it against a regular expression.

```
my $string = "watch download Buffy the Vampire Slayer Season 1 Episode 1 Gorillavid";

if ($string =~ m!(Season\s\d+\sEpisode\s\d+)!){

    $1 =~ s!\s+!!g;

    say $1;

}
```

Now when I run the above code I get `Modification of a read-only value attempted`. Now if I store the value of `$1` in a variable than try to perform a substitution on that variable it works fine.

So, is there any way I can perform a substitution in place without creating a new temporary variable.

PS: Can someone show me how to write the above code as one-liner because I am not able to :)

Comment: What result do you expect? Just "Season1Episode1" without rest of string?

Comment: can't you just do `say s!\s+!!g;`?

Comment: @qnan That will just say 1. You can use the `/r` modifier, though that requires v5.14. And also, you'd need to get the value into another variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't mess with special variables and just capture the data you want, while construction output yourself.

```
$string = "watch download Buffy the Vampire Slayer Season 1 Episode 1 Gorillavid";
if ($string =~ m!Season\s(\d+)\sEpisode\s(\d+)!){
   say("Season$1Episode$2");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want to compress `Season 1 Episode 1` to `Season1Episode1` within the original string

This can be done conveniently using the `@-` and `@+` together with a call to `substr` as an lvalue

This program shows the idea

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "watch download Buffy the Vampire Slayer Season 1 Episode 1 Gorillavid";

if ($string =~ /Season\s+\d+\s+Episode\s+\d+/ ) {

  substr($string, $-[0], $+[0] - $-[0]) =~ s/\s+//g;
  print $string;
}
```

**output**

```
watch download Buffy the Vampire Slayer Season1Episode1 Gorillavid
```

You don't say why you want to write this in a single line, but if you must then this will do it for you

```
perl -pe '/Season\s*\d+\s*Episode\s*\d+/ and substr($_, $-[0], $+[0] - $-[0]) =~ s/\s+//g' myfile
```

Comment: Where can I find the relevant documentation for `@- and @+`.

Comment: @RanRag: Look [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) and search for `@LAST_MATCH_START` and `@LAST_MATCH_END`

Comment: @RanRag `perldoc -v @-` (use appropriate quoting to avoid shell interpolation.)

Answer (score 2):

If you use a post-script `for` loop to create a local instance of `$_`, you can chain your substitution with a print (using a comma) to achieve a pre-print processing of the match.

Note that parentheses are not required when using the global `/g` option. Also note that this makes your if-statement redundant, since any non-match will return an empty list to your `for` loop.

```
perl -nlwe 's/\s+//g, print for /Season\s+\d+\s+Episode\s+\d+/g;' yourfile.txt
```

In your script, it looks like this. Note that the if-statement is replaced with a for loop.

```
for ( $string =~ /Season\s+\d+\s+Episode\s+\d+/g ) {
    s/\s+//g;  # implies $_ =~ s/\s+//g
    say;       # implies say $_

}
```

This is mainly to demonstrate the one-liner. You may insert a lexical variable instead of using `$_`, e.g. `for my $match ( ... )` if you want increased readability.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string =~ s{(?<=Season)\s*(\d+)\s*(Episode)\s*(\d+)}{$1$3$2};
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
perl -pi -e 'if($_=~/Season\s\d+\sEpisode\s\d/){s/\s+//g;}' file
```

tested below:

```
XXX> cat temp
watch download Buffy the Vampire Slayer Season 1 Episode 1 Gorillavid
XXX> perl -pi -e 'if($_=~/Season\s\d+\sEpisode\s\d/){s/\s+//g;}' temp
XXX> cat temp
watchdownloadBuffytheVampireSlayerSeason1Episode1GorillavidXXX>
```

Comment: Why there is a downvote when the solution is correct.the modification is done inline as you can see.